# Azure CDN Rules Engine set cookie from header

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, verizon

I would like to create a rule in Azure CDN to set a cookie based on the value of a request header. Is it possible ?

For example:
Catch `Authorization` request header, get it's value and set to the response header `set-cookie` with the value of the Authorization header ?